# How to make Jquery Click function with multiple radio button with different id in the last name like #radio_1, #radio_2, #radio_3

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Here my HTML Code

```
<label><input name="radio" id="radio" type="radio" value="1"></input> <span>Radio 1</span></label>
<label><input name="radio" id="radio" type="radio" value="2"></input> <span>Radio 2</span></label>
<label><input name="radio" id="radio" type="radio" value="3"></input> <span>Radio 3</span></label>
```

And this is my JQuery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($) {
       $(document).ready(function(){

           $('#radio').click(function(){
               var ongkir = $(this).val();
               alert(ongkir);
           });

       });
   })(jQuery);
</script>
```

and the result just value 1, how i get value 2 and 3 ?

Comment: why not use class attribute?

Comment: You need to have different id's for each of the radio buttons. and you can hook the JQuery on to a class name or the name attribute for the radio button set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique only the first element with `id` get selected. So always use `class` for the group of elements.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $('.radio').click(function() {
      var ongkir = $(this).val();
      alert(ongkir);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input name="radio" class="radio" type="radio" value="1"></input> <span>Radio 1</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input name="radio" class="radio" type="radio" value="2"></input> <span>Radio 2</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input name="radio" class="radio" type="radio" value="3"></input> <span>Radio 3</span>
</label>
```

Comment: @ariefbruce : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`id` have to be unique! But you can use the `name` too, without any other change. Or you can use a `class` or many other selectors ...

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[name=radio]').click(function(){
        var ongkir = $(this).val();
        alert(ongkir);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="1"></input> <span>Radio 1</span>
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="2"></input> <span>Radio 2</span>
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="3"></input> <span>Radio 3</span>
```